# How to evaluate feature detection algorithm

Tags: computer-vision, feature-extraction, evaluation, sift

I have developed a project where I try to find features or points of interest in images
I used two known algorithms which are Harris Corner Detector and SIFT.

I'm looking for a way to create some sort of ground truth or to think of some parameters and some threshold that for each feature I founded I can check if it crosses the threshold or not but I have not found how to do it.

Another thing I thought is to pre-determine and sign manually points of interest by looking at the images but I think that is not so recommended to evaluate in this way since there are elements in very small scales that the human eye will have a hard to recognize.

I hope I was clear
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on similar problem where my goal was to design an algorithm for keypoint detection and matching in engineering drawing document images.

A good Keypoint is any image pixel which have very rich features(keypoint descriptor) which can be further used to easily differentiate from a different Keypoint.

Here is what you can do to measure the accuracy of a Keypoint algorithm:

- You can use any Keypoint feature extraction(SIFT features, fast features) and matching algorithm to find match between keypoints recognised by your algorithm
- Count the True and False matches between keypoints to calculate the accuracy metrics which will tell about the accuracy of Keypoint detection algorithm for your task.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I understand what you mean. The thing is that my algorithm is SIFT and it is not that I wrote my own algorithm and I can compare it to one of the known algorithms.
My question is basically how do I know how many points were detected correctly and how not for a particular image. And how do I know if it's good? What measure can I say that enough points have been identified correctly?

Comment: If you have annotated the keypoints mannually you can compare them with SIFT ouputs but its difficult to decide which keypoints are more relevant for your task.

Comment: My idea is that Given 2 tasks, task-A, task-b and if task-b is derived from task-a then accuracy of task-b is also a function of task-a, so in such scenario we can use task-b's accuracy to estimate the task-a's accuracy.